# partial search collections java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am trying to write code in Java  for a mp3 class. I wish to be able to complete a  full or partial search on the title and artist and it will display on the songs containing the partial string.

This is the code I have written so far.. it will only work in a tester if the user enters the full title or full artist name:

Class code

```
public void searchByArtist(String artist){
        for(Song s : songs){
            if(s.getArtist().equalsIgnoreCase(artist)){
                System.out.println(s.toString());
            }
        }

  //search for a song by title  

    public void searchByTitle(String title){
        for(Song s : songs){
            if(s.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title)){
                System.out.println(s.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Tester code

```
 case 4:
    keyIn.nextLine(); //clear the buffer of the previous option
        System.out.println();
             System.out.print("Please enter Title: ");
                   title = keyIn.nextLine();
                       player.searchByTitle(title);
                                break;

case 5:
keyIn.nextLine(); //clear the buffer of the previous option
System.out.println();
System.out.print("Please enter Artist: ");
artist = keyIn.nextLine();
player.searchByArtist(artist);
break;
```

Comment: ""it will only work in a tester if the user enters the full title or full artist name:"" - give some more details, like what do you expect to happen, what actually happens, what errors are you getting (if any..), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match partially *and* in a case insensitive way, a simple way is to replace `equalsIgnoreCase` with `toLowerCase()` and then `contains`, for example:

```
String search = artist.toLowerCase();
for (Song s : songs) {
    if (s.getArtist().toLowerCase().contains(search)) {
        System.out.println(s.toString());
    }
}
```

Note that `toLowerCase()` is locale specific. If the titles are not in the default locale, then make sure to specify the appropriate `Locale` as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me .  It worked I am very happy I added an else statement at the bottom to print out System.out.println("No artist of that name");  ...........but it prints out out many times depending on the number of songs in the playlist.

Comment: For your next problem, add a flag inside the loop, set it to true when you find a match, and print "no artist" after the loop, only if the flag was not set. Good luck!